# jquery target element in iframe not working

Tags: jquery, iframe

This code does hide the complete iframe, so I targetted the iframe correct

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('iframe[id^="_Liferay_widget"]').hide();
})
</script>
```

But this code doesn't hide all divs inside the iframe.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('iframe[id^="_Liferay_widget"]').contents().find('div').hide();
})
</script>
```

What do I do wrong? The iframe is on a subdomain of the maindomain and in development tools in safari I have restrictions for local files turned off. I don't see any message in console.

Comment: so, you want to hide all the divs? or just a specific div?

Comment: I want to target specific H4's in the iframe. This was just as example I can not target elements in the iframe. And I have not clue why.

Comment: share some HTML and the div you want to hide

Answer (score 1):

Try targeting with this code:

```
$(function(){
    var f=$('#foo')
    f.load(function(){ 
        f.contents().find('#DivID).hide();
    });
});
```

Just add the DIV ID you want to hide.